# Present participle, gerund, or modifier

Tags: gerunds, present-tense, modifiers, participles

Which one of the following is right?

1) I am a doctor working in a hospital.

2) I am, a doctor, working in a hospital.

3) I am a doctor, working in a hospital.

Does "working" modify "doctor" in the first option?

Comment: Doctor, working in a hospital, reflects redundancy, somewhat like 'labour room 'for women.' In terms of grammar, the first and third are no doubt correct; second is correct but such usages are rare.

Comment: 2. is ungrammatical, 3. is possible but somewhat infelicitous. 1. is OK, where the gerund-participial clause "working in a hospital" modifies "doctor".

Comment: Hey Bill, Why is 2 ungrammatical?

Comment: Because in this case "a doctor" is a complement of "am" and cannot be separated from it with a comma.

Comment: They are all grammatical. I disagree with the previous comments that 2) isn't. It's being used as a parenthetical aside: *I am (a doctor) working in a hospital.* It's not a normal punctuation *style*, but it's still valid.